# Which database engines support IP addresses as a native type?

Tags: database, ip-address

I'm trying to find databases with support for IP addresses as a native type (as opposed to storing as a string, or an unsigned integer, which at least one commenter has already pointed out won't work for IPv6). The primary reason I'm looking for this is ease of development. For example, sorting on a "native" IP address column would be correct (as opposed to when it's stored as a string). I would assume support for such a type would also include useful operations such as determining if an IP address is inside a specified network for use in WHERE clauses.

The only one I'm aware of so far is PostgreSQL with its `inet` class. Does anyone have any others?

Comment: Why do you need such a datatype? What operations or conversions does it have (or that you need it to have) that other datatypes don't have?

Comment: If you don't find native support, bear in mind that an unsigned int will not suffice for IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @Loadmaster For example computing subnets, netmasks, broadcast addresses, sorting, formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a domain : domain are made for thing like this !

Comment: Alas not every database flavour supports user-defined domains.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to *which* engines, but if your DB doesn't support it, wrapping it in a function or defining a custom type should be pretty straight forward. I did something similar for GUIDs in Informix a while back.